# возведение в степень цикл while

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h >
# include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    long x = 0, i = 0, y = LONG_MAX, s;
    while (x < y && x >=0) {
        i++;
        x = i * i * i * i * i;
        printf("%d\n", x);


    }

    _getch();
}
```

помогите пжл, как написать в коде что каждое следующее число возведенное в степень больше предыдущего, ну чтоб переполнения не было.

Comment: `x < y` сравнение не имеет смысла. логичнее было бы писать что-то в духе `y/i/i/i/i > 0` И да, не знаю как в С, а в С++ переполнение знакового числа это UB и компилятор может вообще всё поубирать.

Comment: Какое число Вы хотите возвести в степень?

Comment: почему? x < y означает x < LONG_MAX

Comment: @Notoriuss а как оно может быть _больше_ Максимума?

Comment: все числа в 5 степень, не выходящих за диапазон LONG_MAX

Comment: может быть я неправильно написал код, если не сложно подскажите как исправить

Comment: Переполнение при умножении лучше всего отлавливать делением (проверять, что деление результата умножения дает исходный сомножитель)

Comment: код указанный выше выводит все числа в 5 степени но в конце случается переполнение, а нужно без переполнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long x = 0, i = 0, y = LONG_MAX;
while (1) {
    i++;
    if ( (((y / i) / i) / i) / i < i )
      break;
    x = i * i * i * i * i;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: говорит идентификатор true  не определен

Comment: ребят спасибо, я проверял делением до того как написать, но я кое что не учел , скобки при каждом делении не поставил

Comment: а теперь все хорошо

Comment: @Notoriuss Хорошо, когда все хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева.

Comment: говорит через 2 минуты))

Comment: а для отрицательных тот же цикл делать ток минусовать?

Comment: а зачем скобок сколько?

Comment: и вообще лучше `!=0` писать вместо `>0`

Comment: @pavel Скобки не нужны. Я поставил их как напоминание о том, в каком порядке будет выполнено деление.

Comment: @Notoriuss для отрицательных - делать то же самое, кроме: `printf("-%d\n", x);`

Comment: а ноль как вывести?

Comment: @Notoriuss я не понимаю, в чем трудность?

Comment: да не все норм, отдельно ноль выведу, я хотел через цикл чтоб с 0 начиналось возведение

Comment: @Notoriuss `if ( i != 0 && (((y / i) / i) / i) / i < i )`

Comment: @Notoriuss ( перенесите `i++;` в конец цикла

Comment: как так то я же сразу так написал когда второй цикл писал, а сейчас норм скомпилися, я так понял студио у меня тормозит))

Comment: Igor, можете назвать инвариант всего кода или цикла?